# Rysyslog is not using the short hostname, and is instead using the FQDN

Tags: rsyslog

I have an ryslog server (V8.2112.0) running on Ubuntu (22.04.2), with very basic setup to receive logs from Cisco switches. The server and all the switches are in the same domain.

I'm trying to use the `%hostname%` variable for the log file locations, and specifically use the short hostname. From what I can find online, it's supposed to use the short hostname if the rsyslog server is in the same domain as the clients.

When I run the `hostname` command on the server, I get `rsyslogserver`, and when I run `hostname --fqdn` i get `rsyslogserver.domain.local`.

All of the devices that send logs to the server are in the same `.domain.local`, and use it in their FQDN.

Since all of my clents are in the same domain, I want the server to use the short hostname instead, because I have no need for the `.domain.local`, but it is always using the FQDN.

I've done some searching, and the only related things I can find are the exact opposite issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

To configure your rsyslog server to use the short hostname instead of the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) when saving logs, you can follow these steps:

1. **Edit the Rsyslog Configuration File**:
   Open the Rsyslog configuration file for editing. On Ubuntu, the default configuration file is usually located at `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.

   ```bash
   sudo nano /etc/rsyslog.conf
   ```
2. **Modify the Templates**:
   Within the configuration file, locate the section where log templates are defined. You can create a custom template that uses the `%hostname%` variable with the desired format. For example:

   ```
   $template MyCustomTemplate, "%HOSTNAME:1:$%\t%msg%\n"
   ```

   In this example, `%HOSTNAME:1:$%` will use the short hostname.
3. **Configure Log Files**:
   Update your log file definitions to use the custom template:

   ```
   local0.*    /var/log/myapp.log;MyCustomTemplate
   ```

   Replace `local0.*` and `/var/log/myapp.log` with your actual log facility and file path.
4. **Restart Rsyslog**:
   After making these changes, restart the Rsyslog service to apply the new configuration:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
   ```